# Does PHP activerecord basic CRUD actions prevent SQL injection?

Tags: php, activerecord, sql-injection

Considering the example below, does PHP activerecord prevent SQL injection on basic create? I can find numerous examples and instructions on the finders, but nothing on the safety of what I do here.

```
    $p = new Person();
    $p->firstname = $_POST["firstname"];
    $p->emailaddress = $email_enc; (encoded from $_POST["email"])
    $p->save();
```

EDIT: I'm not asking about preventing "ordinary" PHP SQL injection. This question is specific for PHP activerecord basic CRUD actions

Comment: That depends on how you are passing values to the DB. Are you using PDO and prepared statements?

Comment: Not a dupe, this is specific PHP activerecord framework question(http://www.phpactiverecord.org/). Thus not using PDO directly, I don't know what activerecord uses under the hood

Comment: Sorry, I've never come across that framework before, I thought you were referring to the pattern. You could check their code and see what they're doing.

Comment: However, I still think this is a dupe as comparing the [source code](https://github.com/jpfuentes2/php-activerecord/blob/master/lib/Connection.php) to the answers in the linked question would give you your answer, as Chris has indicated in his answer below.

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this](https://github.com/jpfuentes2/php-activerecord/blob/master/lib/Connection.php) source code, phpactiverecord uses PDO to connect to the database. Based on the top answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134099/are-pdo-prepared-statements-sufficient-to-prevent-sql-injection?rq=1) question, you are protected from 1st order SQL injections.